# How to reach the same performance with the C# mongo driver than PyMongo in python?

Tags: c#, python, mongodb

In a current benchmark about mongodb drivers, we have noticed a huge difference in performance between python and .Net (core or framework).

And the a part of the difference can be explained by this in my opinion.

We obtained the following results :

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Metric                  ┃ Csharp   ┃ Python  ┃ ratio p/c ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ Ratio Duration/Document ┃ 24.82    ┃ 0.03    ┃ 0.001     ┃
┃ Duration (ms)           ┃ 49 638   ┃ 20 016  ┃ 0.40      ┃
┃ Count                   ┃ 2000     ┃ 671 972 ┃ 336       ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

We took a look to the memory allocation in C# and we noticed a ping pong between download phases of a BsonChunck and deserialization. (Normal as it's by batch.) But the download phases were very long. So we took a look to the network trace of the different queries as mongo use TCP/IP:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Metric                        ┃ Csharp    ┃ Python     ┃ ratio p/c ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ Packets/sec to db             ┃ 30        ┃ 160        ┃ 5.3       ┃
┃ Packets/sec from DB           ┃ 120 - 150 ┃ 750 - 1050 ┃ ~6.5      ┃
┃ Packet count to db            ┃ 1560      ┃ 2870       ┃ 1.84      ┃
┃ Packet count from db          ┃ 7935      ┃ 13663      ┃ 1.7       ┃
┃ Packet average length to db   ┃ 73.6      ┃ 57.6       ┃ 0.74      ┃
┃ Packet average length from db ┃ 1494      ┃ 1513       ┃ 1.01      ┃
┃ Max TCP Errors/sec            ┃ 20        ┃ 170        ┃ 8.5       ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

For the config file, the result is stunning only with the following one :

```
{
    "connectionString": "mongodb://ip.of.the.mongo:27018",
    "dbname" : "mydb",
    "colname" : "mycollection",
    "query" : {},
    "projection" :{},
    "limit" : 2000,
    "batchsize": 10
}
```

The latency for one object is impressive : 0.03 ms for python and 24.82 for csharp.

Do you have some insights about this difference ? Do you know a way to reach the same performance in C# than in Python ?
Thank you in advance :-)

To do the benchmark, we are using these two codes :

Python (pymongo driver):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pymongo
import time
import json
import os

queries_dir = "../queries"
results_dir = "../results"

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(queries_dir):
    for f in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + f
        print(filepath)
        conf = json.load(open(filepath))
        conf["language"] = "python"
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(conf["connectionString"])
        db = client[conf["dbname"]]
        col = db[conf["colname"]]

        initConnection = col.find({}, {}).limit(1)
        for element in initConnection:
            print(element)

        input("Press enter to continue.")

        res = col.find(conf["query"], conf["projection"])
        returned = 0

        start = time.time()
        for i in res:
            returned += 1
        duration = (time.time() - start) * 1000
        conf["duration"] = duration
        conf["returned"] = returned
        conf["duration_per_returned"] = float(duration) / float(returned) 
        d = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        fr = open(results_dir + os.sep + d + "_" + conf["language"] + "_" + f,"w")
        json.dump(conf, fr, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        fr.close()
        print(json.dumps(conf,indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

And for .Net (MongoDB.Driver):

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var queryDirectory = dir.Replace(@"csharp\benchmark\benchmark\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2", string.Empty) + "queries"; 
            var resultDirectory = dir.Replace(@"csharp\benchmark\benchmark\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2", string.Empty)+ "results";
            var configurationFiles = Directory.GetFiles(queryDirectory);
            foreach (var file in configurationFiles)
            {
                var configuration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BenchmarkConfiguration>(File.ReadAllText(file));
                var collection = new MongoClient(configuration.ConnectionString)
                    .GetDatabase(configuration.Database)
                    .GetCollection<BsonDocument>(configuration.Collection);
                var filters = BsonDocument.Parse((string)(configuration.Query.ToString()));
                var projection = BsonDocument.Parse((string)(configuration.Projection.ToString()));
                var query = collection.Find(filters, new FindOptions { BatchSize = configuration.BatchSize }).Project(projection).Limit(configuration.Limit);

                var initconnection = collection.Find(new BsonDocument { }).Limit(1).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine(initconnection.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                var watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();
                var results = query.ToList();
                watch.Stop();
                var time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                var now = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");
                var report = new BenchmarkResult(configuration, time, results.Count());
                File.WriteAllText($"{resultDirectory}/{now}_csharp_{Path.GetFileName(file)}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(report, Formatting.Indented));
            }
        }
    }
```

OLD METRICS : Before removing the connection pull from the benchmark loop.

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Metric                  ┃ Csharp   ┃ Python  ┃ ratio p/c ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ Ratio Duration/Document ┃ 26.07    ┃ 0.06    ┃ 0.002     ┃
┃ Duration (ms)           ┃ 52 145.0 ┃ 41 981  ┃ 0.80      ┃
┃ Count                   ┃ 2000     ┃ 671 972 ┃ 336       ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┛
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Metric                        ┃ Csharp    ┃ Python     ┃ ratio p/c ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ Packets/sec to db             ┃ 30        ┃ 150        ┃ 5         ┃
┃ Packets/sec from DB           ┃ 120 - 180 ┃ 750 - 1050 ┃ ~6        ┃
┃ Packet count to db            ┃ 1540      ┃ 2815       ┃ 1.8       ┃
┃ Packet count from db          ┃ 7946      ┃ 13700      ┃ 1.7       ┃
┃ Packet average length to db   ┃ 74        ┃ 59         ┃ 0.80      ┃
┃ Packet average length from db ┃ 1493      ┃ 1512       ┃ 1         ┃
┃ Max TCP Errors/sec            ┃ 10        ┃ 320        ┃ 32        ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Projection issue with pymongo

The performance difference between C# and python driver you are experimenting is due to a very tiny detail that lay down in how python `pymongo` lib understands the empty `{ }` projection.

In mongodb-shell and in the C# driver, `{ }` projection does return the whole document. There is actually no projection at all. It's likely to be considered as the default behavior since mongodb-shell is acting like that.

However, `{ }` projection in python with `pymongo` does only return the `_id` field !
The more the documents are heavy, the more time it takes your C# code to download the documents, while your python code is only taking the very tiny _ids.

### Fixing your bench code

If you change from

```py
res = col.find(conf["query"], conf["projection"]) #projection being { }.
for i in res:
    print(i) # Only print Id fields.
    returned += 1
```

to

```py
res = col.find(conf["query"])
for i in res:
    print(i) # Whole document 'downloaded' and printed.
    returned += 1
```

You will notice that both are performing well.

Comment: Hello :-) 
You are right, as the python code and c# one were not done by the same person, the code seemed equivalent to me. Important difference to note. Thank you.
After running, the two code take ages to perform.

Comment: Might be useful to validate the benchmark with a projection to ensure both languages are performing :)

Answer (score 3):

After taking a (fast) look to `mongo-csharp-driver` source, I could say that:

- Connection pooling is mostly cluster related

For these point, here we have:

- [`ExclusiveConnectionPool`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/ConnectionPools/ExclusiveConnectionPool.cs) based on [`ConnectionPoolSettings`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Configuration/ConnectionPoolSettings.cs) who all default values are `Optional<>` or aka `default` + default hardcoded value.
- This are called through `ExclusiveConnectionPoolFactory` > `Server` > `ClusterBuilder` > `ServerFactory` > `Cluster` (or any `IClusterableServerFactory`?) who end at `SingleServerCluster` or `MultiServerCluster`

Looking fastly through `mongo-python-driver`, pooling is not applied in the same way/context. It's applied for direct-server connection, without any need of cluster conf.

Regarding to the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-pool-options), just adding `minPoolSize` & `maxPoolSize` will do the job/trick.

Like `$"{yourconnectionstring}/?appname=pooledClient&minPoolSize=5&maxPoolSize=100`

[mongod logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtCvw.png)

The question to ask (to the team/maintainers) is: *Why is pooling not enabled by default, for non-cluster configuration?*

---

About the performance for single vs multi vs pooled `MongoClient` in 2.9.1

- `ReadMultiShared`: 4 clients, in a `Parallel.ForEach`, with skip+limit
- `ReadMultiSharedAsync`: 2 clients, async call, with skip+limit
- `ReadAllSingle`: 1 client
- `ReadAllPooled`: 1 client with *pool*

Mongod running in a local Docker.

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
Intel Core i7-4790 CPU 3.60GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100-preview8-013656
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.2.2 (CoreCLR 4.6.27317.07, CoreFX 4.6.27318.02), 64bit RyuJIT
  Job-VBWGDB : .NET Core 2.2.2 (CoreCLR 4.6.27317.07, CoreFX 4.6.27318.02), 64bit RyuJIT

Toolchain=.NET Core 2.2

|               Method |         Mean |        Error |       StdDev | Rank |     Gen 0 |     Gen 1 | Gen 2 |   Allocated |
|--------------------- |-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|-----:|----------:|----------:|------:|------------:|
|          BsonReadOne |     806.5 us |     15.94 us |     23.37 us |    1 |    4.8828 |         - |     - |    21.15 KB |
|    BasicClassReadOne |     827.9 us |     16.34 us |     33.75 us |    1 |    3.9063 |         - |     - |    19.99 KB |
|      ReadMultiShared | 531,369.5 us | 10,611.11 us | 26,029.23 us |    3 | 6000.0000 | 2000.0000 |     - | 30080.81 KB |
| ReadMultiSharedAsync | 644,437.8 us | 12,396.64 us | 11,595.83 us |    4 | 7000.0000 | 2000.0000 |     - |    93.48 KB |
|        ReadAllSingle | 512,507.9 us | 10,172.46 us | 11,306.67 us |    2 | 6000.0000 | 2000.0000 |     - | 39375.26 KB |
|        ReadAllPooled | 513,240.1 us | 10,423.18 us | 18,255.36 us |    2 | 6000.0000 | 2000.0000 |     - | 39375.26 KB |
```

[src](https://gist.github.com/Herve-M/01558b9903bdc522afc93b89e27ebb1c)

Edit: using `BatchSize` seem really to impact the perf. of queries too. Using batching, `ReadMultiShared` perform better against a client with it. Without it, it underperforms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Your fast look to the driver raises some questions about the pooling as on our current mongo, it has no real effect.

Answer (score 0):

the c# driver uses connection pooling and the recommendation is to make the `MongoClient` a static/singleton outside of the loop and re-use it within the loop or anywhere else in an application.

also the c# driver only connects to the mongodb server when the very first action is performed. which in your case is at `query.ToList()`. so when benchmarking performance, the very first delay in initiating connection should be ignored. so i'd recommend to perform some other action once before starting the timer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
Usually, we hide our repositories behind singleton and it was their low performance that makes us decide to do the benchmark.

I have updated the first post with your insights and... Python 'gains' in performance on csharp. But the gain in C# is minimal.

Comment: maybe open a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/CSHARP and see what the driver authors have to say about it...

Comment: Hello, done, thank you. :-) I will keep this thread updated.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2712